# Optimized SQL Query to retrieve a Particular set of records from Microsoft SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve the set of data from a column in the table.
My Scenario is:
Iam having a table with name table1_data , In that table there is a Column with name "clm_Name", The data in the column is like this

```
a
b
c
a
b
c
a
b
a
b
c
a
a
b
c
```

I want to retrieve the data when a b c are in order if order changes it should not retrieve.(i.e, If we write a query on given data the output should be **a b c a b c** a b **a b c** a **a b c**) only the bolded letters should be shown in output.

Comment: is `a b c` a value in a row? Or is it one row `a`, one row `b`, one row `c`? If later, be aware that in SQL there is no such concept as  'before', 'after', 'first' etc unless you specify an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Without a column specifying the ordering, your question makes no sense.

Comment: Do you have an identity column that you want to use as 'ordered as input'?

Comment: @JoeC nhow this is a bad design and would cause endless headaches with updates - Gordon is totally correct - a table should be a unordered set. The OP should revisit his design.

Comment: I am asking his intent.  I tend to try to answer peoples questions and maybe supply some advice on the side.  For instance if he answers yes I can give him a query and then recommend he use a datetime rather than an identity column.  Also, although I agree with Gordon in principle, by definition a heap is an unordered set and a table with a clustered index is an ordered set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a column to sort you can do as follows:

```
DECLARE @Tbl TABLE (OrderId INT, val NVARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @Tbl        
VALUES  
(1,'a'),
(2,'b'),
(3,'c'),
(4,'a'),
(5,'b'),
(6,'c'),
(7,'a'),
(8,'b'),
(9,'a'),
(10,'b'),
(11,'c'),
(12,'a'),
(13,'a'),
(14,'b'),
(15,'c')


;WITH  CTE
AS
(   
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT OrderId)) RowId
    FROM @Tbl
), Result
AS 
(
    SELECT  
        CurrRow.RowId
    FROM
        CTE CurrRow LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT CTE.val , CTE.RowId - 1 RowId FROM CTE) NextRow ON CurrRow.RowId = NextRow.RowId LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT CTE.val , CTE.RowId + 1 RowId FROM CTE) PrivRow ON CurrRow.RowId = PrivRow.RowId
    WHERE
        PrivRow.val = 'a' AND 
        CurrRow.val = 'b' AND 
        NextRow.val = 'c'
)


SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    CTE C
WHERE
    C.RowId IN ( 
                    SELECT Result.RowId FROM Result
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT Result.RowId - 1 FROM Result
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT Result.RowId + 1 FROM Result
                )
ORDER BY C.OrderId
```

Output:

```
OrderId val RowId
1       a   1
2       b   2
3       c   3
4       a   4
5       b   5
6       c   6
9       a   9
10      b   10
11      c   11
13      a   13
14      b   14
15      c   15
```

Comment: Hello @Neer
I just came across another scenario as given below:

i/p


    'a
b
c
x
**a**
y
**b**
z
**c**'

o/p


    'a
b
c
a
b
c'

Could you please help me with this ?

Comment: Input `a b c x a y b z c` Output: `a b c a b c`? How do you do this?

Comment: Hello @NEER

Please find the snapshot from the url for reference

[link](https://1drv.ms/i/s!At3s_I2cf5TtiE0Q6i8uGzIhdODq)

Comment: Yes, we want as the same u posted in the comment.

Comment: @MohanRajesh You should do that in a `WHILE` loop. It is hard to get this result.